# How to add erlang packages into an elixir application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to build a release of my elixir app using `edeliver` but I am getting the following error.

```
==> Failed to build release:

    Undefined applications: [xmerl]
```

I am trying to add `xmerl` to my list of `deps` in the `mix.exs` file but I am unsure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

This is the list of deps that are currently in my project...

```
defp deps do
  [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
   {:appsignal, "~> 1.0"},
   {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
   {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
   {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
   {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
   {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
   {:phoenix_html_sanitizer, "~> 1.0.0"},
   {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
   {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
   {:earmark, "~> 1.1"},
   {:comeonin, "~> 3.0"},
   {:credo, "~> 0.7.2", only: [:dev, :test]},
   {:timex, "~> 3.0"},
   {:segment, github: "tonydaly/analytics-elixir"},
   {:bamboo, "~> 0.7"},
   {:bamboo_smtp, "~> 1.2.1"},
   {:mock, "~> 0.2.0", only: :test},
   {:faker, "~> 0.7"},
   {:wallaby, "~> 0.16.1"},
   {:ecto_factory, "~> 0.0.6"},
   {:oxleas_adhd, in_umbrella: true},
   {:plug, "~>1.3.5", override: true}
 ]
end
```

Comment: Can you please show your mix.exs file, specifically the deps section.

Comment: @JustinWood `mix` file has no _sections_ :) `deps` is a plain old good function, called from `project` callback in the scaffold generated by default.

Comment: @JustinWood I have updated the question to show the deps

Comment: @mudasobwa I understand that mix has no real sections. But colloquially asking for a section should be understood.

Answer (score 3):

I would put the correct answer here for the sake of future visitors.

`mix.exs` file should declare two callbacks: `project` and (optionally) `application`.

The latter is used when the project is intended to be run as an application and is out of scope of this question. The former must return a keyword list, describing the current [Mix.Project](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Project.html#content). This keyword list might apparently contain `deps` keyword to return a list of dependencies of this project. These dependencies would be semi-automatically managed (fetched, rebuilt etc) by `mix` tool.

By default, `mix new` task generates a scaffold for the `project` callback, returning this list like:

```rb
  def project do
    [
      app: :blah,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.7-dev",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps() # ⇐ HERE
    ]
  end
```

if one would stick to using the suggested scaffold, they should implement the private function `deps` (see the last line above.)

If you have a single dependency, just do it inplace:

```rb
  def project do
    [
      app: :blah,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.7-dev",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: [{:exmerl, "~> 0.1"}] # ⇐ HERE
    ]
  end
```

[`exmerl`](https://hex.pm/packages/exmerl) is an Elixir wrapper for `xmerl`, or [`exml`](https://github.com/expelledboy/exml), or any other.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have tried adding the `{:xmerl, "~> 1.3"}` as you suggested in your answer but I am getting the following error...


    "`Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/xmerl' from registry (using cache)
    This could be because the package does not exist, it was spelled incorrectly or you don't have permissions to it`".  It looks like this package does not exist. I know that it is part of erlang however. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should be indeed https://hex.pm/packages/exmerl , I missed it’s pure erlang, sorry. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have also tried adding this package but I am getting the same error. It seems as though it my be an issue `edeliver` which is running the build for my application as I am not getting the error when I run this locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
def deps do
  [
    {:xmerl, "~> 1.3.16"}
  ]
end
```

you must fetch the deps,

```
$ mix deps.get
```

Comment: 1. `deps` should be a private function, 2. `deps` is not a callback and won’t do anything in the `mix.exs` file, _unless called while returning `deps` from `project` callback_.

Comment: Yes it should be defp not def